# Office always requests file as anonymous user

Tags: ms-office, webdav

I'm implementing a webdav server. I have everything working fine for anonymous access, but now I want to require authentication.

When a user clicks on a link to open the word document (I'm using the `ms-word:` protocol), Word sends a couple of HTTTP OPTIONS requests, first with an empty `Bearer` value in the `Authorization` header, to which the server responds with a `WWW-Authenticate` header, and everything is working correctly (after the user authenticates with Word, word sends a follow-up HTTP OPTIONS request with a token value in the header).

However, when Word requests the file itself (using HTTP GET), there is no `Authorization` header. I've tried having the server respond with a `401` status, but when it does, Word simply gives up and informs the user the file can't be opened.

What's even more troubling is that, from what I can tell, Word sends the GET and OPTIONS requests in parallel, so at the time it sends the GET request, it has no idea that it will be authenticating with the OPTIONS request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this will always be the answer to the issues I described above, but I think it's a combination of problems I was running into. Here's the basics of how I got around the issues I was having.

1. Delete Office Webdav cache. Office caches information about Webdav servers pretty aggressively. The cache is found in the registry as this location: `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\X\Common\Internet\Server Cache` where X is the current version of Office you have installed. Delete all subkeys that have your server's URL.
2. Do not use `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` for your Webdav. Office seems to behave differently if it knows that your server is local. This may mean needing to add entries into your `hosts` file to "trick" it into thinking your site is on a remote server.
3. If using some sort of federated auth (Azure AD, Google, Facebook, etc.) and you are using bearer tokens, Office needs to be told where to go to authenticate, this is done by responding to non-authenticated requests with a `401` status and the `WWW-Authenticate` header value being set to something like this (I can confirm this works for Azure AD):

```
Bearer authorization_uri="https://login.microsoftonline.com/[Tenant ID]/oauth2/authorize",trusted_issuers="https://login.microsoftonline.com/*/",client_id="[Azure AD App Client ID]"
```

4. Even with the client ID set, it seems like the `Application ID URI` in the app registration needs to match the server's base URL (protocol + host + port)

Comment: Interesting, are you saying you have authentication to your app working with AzureAD? This is not something that worked last time I tried what you are suggesting and I had to implement MS-OFBA.

Comment: Yes, I have it working with Azure AD, Facebook, and Twitter (to my app and MS-OFBA). I have Google authentication working to my app, but something about Google's login page inside office's web view causes office to close the modal window with an error. dialog.

Comment: Hi @BrianBall, we are trying to do the same. But we have an issue after entering the password in Azure login dialog.

AADSTS500011 – The resource principal named [URI] was not found in the tenant named [guid]. This can happen if the application has not been installed by the administrator of the tenant or consented to by any user in the tenant. You might have sent your authentication request to the wrong tenant.

Do you have any specific configuration in Azure?

Comment: I mean we are trying to implement Azure AD without MS-OFBA